# QML stack trace during crash

Tags: qt, qml, lldb

My project is a Qt GUI application in which all views are in QML and Models and Business logic in C++. As the size of the project has grown to 100's of cpp and qml files debugging has becoming more and more difficult.
In Debug mode crashes produced in the C++ code are easily found as stack trace linked to source-code is presented, but crashes due to qml code produces all grayed out stack-trace (ie., pointing to Qt internals etc where in you cannot see the qml file and the line producing the error).

Do you know anyway to do that?

Using:
C++11, Qt/QML 5.2.0, Qt Creator 3.0 on Mac (Clang++, LLDB combination) and Windows (MinGW g++ 4.8.0)

If i put a breakpoint on any javascript function in the qml file then the breakpoint is easily hit during the course of debugging, but the problem is when the application crashes, i've no way of knowing which qml file/line could have participated in the crash and so i can't put the breakpoint beforehand - it should show in the stack-trace but it does not (only shows grayed out stack-trace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's currently possible. However, see [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/development@qt-project.org/msg15647.html) email from Simon on the development mailing list:

> The nature of the beast is that we do have two language environments here and 
>   they do (and can't) share the same stack, so stack traces will always be 
>   separate. However there are ways of determining the "current" JavaScript stack 
>   trace in parallel. Note that this isn't possible with Qt 5.1 or older, but 
>   starting with Qt 5.2 it is possible.
>
> Friedemann was kind enough to lay the infrastructure for that in QtQml and 
>   used it on the Qt Creator side, in a way that could also be used by KDE's 
>   drkonqi:
>
> It will require a little bit of analysis and interaction with gdb, but I think 
>   it's doable. It will require looking at the frames gdb reports, and if you see 
>   functions that take a QV4::ExecutionContext * as a parameter, then you can 
>   extract the "address" from the gdb output and then call the qt_v4StackTrace 
>   function in QtQml from within gdb. It will print out a JavaScript stack trace. 
>   This works rather well and Qt Creator 3.1 provides it through the context menu 
>   in the debugger, if you'd like to try it out yourself.
>
> This way bug reports in KDE that somehow involve Qt JavaScript execution can - 
>   in parallel - include a C++ backtrace and a JS stack trace.

This provides a little bit of context as to why debugging QML applications is the way it is.

I think he is referring to the [Load QML Stack](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-master/creator-debug-mode.html#viewing-call-stack-trace) option in Creator:

> Since the call stack leading to the current position may originate or go through code for which no debug information is available, not all stack frames have corresponding source locations. Stack frames without corresponding source locations are grayed out in the Stack view.
>
> If you click a frame with a known source location, the text editor jumps to the corresponding location and updates the Locals and Expressions view, making it seem like the program was interrupted before entering the function.
>
> To find out which QML file is causing a Qt Quick 2 application to crash, select Load QML Stack in the context menu in the Stack view. The debugger tries to retrieve the JavaScript stack from the stopped executable and prepends the frames to the C++ frames, should it find any. You can click a frame in the QML stack to open the QML file in the editor.

It may not be that useful, but there's also [console.trace()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-debugging.html#trace). That link also links to [Debugging Qt Quick Projects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-3.1/creator-debugging-qml.html).

Comment: ok, so Qt Creator 3.1 should do it? Have you tried it there? I'm currently using Creator 3.0.

Comment: I've updated my answer to point to the feature which I think is the correct one.

Comment: And yep, I've got the "Load QML Stack" feature with Qt Creator 3.1.1.